# magento 2.3 call customer group Name

Tags: customer-account, phtml, magento2.3.3, magento2.3.4, dashboard

i am using magnto 2.3.x,

how can i call the **customer group Name** in phtml

not a customer group ID.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

> **Try this code**

```
 protected $_session;
 protected $_customerGroupCollection;

 public function __construct(
        ................................................
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Group $customerGroupCollection,
        ................................................
    ) {
        ................................................
        $this->_session = $session;
        $this->_customerGroupCollection = $customerGroupCollection;
        ................................................
    }
    public function getGroup()
    {
        $currentGroupId = $this->_session->getCustomer()->getGroupId(); //Get customer group Id 
        $collection = $this->_customerGroupCollection->load($currentGroupId); 
        echo $collection->getCustomerGroupCode();//Get group name
    }
```

> **Call this method in phtml**

```
$block->getGroup();
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: click on this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kt-39DnoxXw_EPbzIDYE3wnbne0mWx7M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110933/discussion-on-answer-by-msquare-magento-2-3-call-customer-group-name).